# MySQL query or stored procedure that calls itself recursively and returns all nodes for selected parent

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, treeview, parent-child

```
id | parent_id | name
-------------------------
1  | null      | World
2  | 1         | Sri Lanka
3  | 1         | America
4  | 2         | South Province
5  | 2         | Western Province
6  | 4         | Galle
7  | 6         | Wakwella
8  | 3         | New York
```

I need a  MySQL query or stored procedure that calls itself recursively and returns all nodes,child nodes and leaf nodes for selected "id" .

As a example:

When i want to select all child of id=2
Result should be,

```
South Province
Western Province
Galle
Wakwella
```

When i want to select all child of id=3
Result should be,

```
New York
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a similar question was answered here:
     https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161

You need to use stored procedures for this.